# making a string into date day year format

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

I am using big commerce and i have set a product end date in which it outputs text such as `(Must be before 18th Apr 2014)` . It outputs a date in only this format, apart from this i have no other option to get the date . I need to take out 18th apr 2014 and store it into three different variables and also change apr to 04 or any month to digits format . I can use `replace`  to replace `Must be before` and get only `18th Apr 2014` But now how to achieve what i wanted ? Also is there a easy way to get `Event date` according to product id ? I can only think of this way to at least store these into variables